# Grails: Run Application Error ant-launcher-1.9.4.pom

Tags: grails, ant

**When I ran the grails application, I got the following output:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration24'.

Could not resolve org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4.

Required by:

project : > org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:2.4.10

project : > org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:2.4.10 > org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4

Could not resolve org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4.

Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.9.4/ant-launcher-1.9.4.pom'.

Could not GET 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.9.4/ant-launcher-1.9.4.pom'.

This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (repo.grails.org)

**The StackTrace was as follows:**

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.grails.build.parsing.ScriptNameResolver.resolvesTo(ScriptNameResolver.groovy:34)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile$_handleCommand_closure9.doCall(AbstractProfile.groovy:487)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:486)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:378)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closure6.doCall(GrailsCli.groovy:469)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closure6.call(GrailsCli.groovy)

**I downloaded ant-launcher-1.9.4.pom manually and copied it in the lib folder also, but the error was not solved.**

Answer (score 0):

You can put

> compile org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4.

on `build.gradle` file then recompile